# crescent of pastry / pastry of crescent

Tags: meaning-in-context, prepositions

> a small ( ) topped with cheese

For the contents in parenthesis, should I use ***crescent of pastry*** or ***pastry of crescent***? Is there any difference between the two phrases?

Comment: After looking up both words in a dictionary, why would you assume that a dough made of moon-shape makes any sense?

Comment: What exactly is this pastry? Do you have a picture?

Comment: Do you mean a crescent-shaped pastry that is not a *[croissant](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Laugencroissants.JPG)*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Crescent of pastry* is correct. It is essentially a contraction of 'crescent **made of** pastry', which is why 'pastry of crescent' doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 3):

You can say a *crescent of pastry*. You could also say a *pastry crescent* or a *cresent-shaped pastry*.

Answer (score 0):

You can also say

> Pastry **in the form of a crescent**.